# Apache ignite stop working after a while on ubuntu

Tags: asp.net-core, ignite

My application is on the .net core platform and uses apache ignite inside itself.
everything works truly on windows, but on ubuntu, the application stops working after a while.
I attached the log files.
[log 01](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GkxF41L6E0in1SMmvx71Y0wDgjq32Oah/view?usp=sharing)
[log 02](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1joRaZCo2in34HVqY4PUjjr7tcn1uNQsT/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: The log files are not accessible, please put them somewhere with public access.

Comment: The links fixed.

Comment: The relevant log information should be within this question, not on external servers that might go away after some time. Please read [ask] and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Both logs end with `*** stack smashing detected ***: terminated`.

This happens on Linux with .NET Core when NullReferenceException occurs in user code. The reason is that both .NET and Java use SIGSEGV to handle certain exceptions, including `NullPointerException` and `NullReferenceException`.

The fix for this issue exists in .NET Core 3.0 and later: **try setting the `COMPlus_EnableAlternateStackCheck` environment variable to `1` before starting the node**. This should reveal the exception stack trace.

https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/net-specific/net-troubleshooting#stack-smashing-detected-dotnet-terminated

Comment: It's worked. Thanks